# How can I turn off CKEditor on certain platforms?

Tags: javascript, mobile, ckeditor

I've been reading a lot of places that show how to set CKEditor into a read-only mode, but that is not what I need.

For iOS/Android (or better: "small/mobile devices"), I'd like to actually turn it off so that I have a plain old `<textarea>` on those devices/platforms (*we don't usually need the fancy stuff; it's just nice to have on a desktop so people can copy/paste from MS Word and not have it blow up*).

Is there a setting I can configure; or can I at least run some Javascript and programmatically turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.env-property-isCompatible) flag. You can always change it a bit (see [the definition](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/efc73cb1b49a750ee0a46158474b91d9876416ae/core/env.js#L277)).

Alternatively, wrap your `CKEDITOR.replace()` (or `inline()`) call in some sort of conditional.

Comment: Thanks! The code I wound up using was `if (CKEDITOR.env.mobile) { CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = false }` and I had to put this right after the `<script>` tag that includes CKEditor.